# With multi-line labels, how to show the 2nd line only for labels that need it?

Tags: qgis, labeling, mac

Mac OSX 10.6.8 QGIS 1.8.0 : I've two columns in the attribute table, name, and name2 for those labels that need to be 2 lines; multiline labelling is checked. But when I use "name"||'\n'||"name2" I only get labels when there is a printable entry for both name and name2. Can you spot what I'm missing to show the 2nd line only for labels that need it?

Answer (score 1):

Thats possible only with QGIS Master at the moment:

> "Strecke" || '-n' ||   CASE WHEN  length( "Kilometer"  ) > 0  THEN  "Kilometer"  ELSE ' ' END

You don't have the CASE statements in Lisboa.

Comment: Am I not correct that '' above is a null string? If so, I don't see why the case statement is needed when "Kilometer" is already null.

Comment: No, I used a single blank. A Null string seems to break the labelling.